# Processing python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a variable `message` is of type `dict`

```
>>> print(message)
{TopicPartition(topic='testing_topic', partition=1): [ConsumerRecord(topic='testing_topic', partition=1, offset=0, timestamp=1499411365748, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value=b'{"url":"http://review.travel.rakuten.co.jp/hotel/voice/158886/", "meta":{"url_cnt":"1185","hotelid":"158886","job_id":"0f3de6d4-34bf-4a1a-a803-5640e8d25932"}}', checksum=-309359221, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=158)]}
```

How to fetch `value` portion from it. 
I tried a lot but I am unable to do it. Please suggest.

I want this.

```
value=b'{"url":"http://review.travel.rakuten.co.jp/hotel/voice/158886/", "meta":{"url_cnt":"1185","hotelid":"158886","job_id":"0f3de6d4-34bf-4a1a-a803-5640e8d25932"}}'
```

Comment: Did you try `message[0]['value']`? It seems the values are contained in a list.

Comment: I am getting key error `print(message[0]['value'])` KeyError: 0

Comment: Without knowing what these `TopicPartition` and `ConsumerRecord` classes are, it's hard to say. But you can try `next(iter(message.values()))[0].value`.

Comment: The message contains function calls and `value` is one of the parameters passed to the `ConsumerRecord` function. If you cannot modify/rewrite the function to spit the `value` parameter out, you can convert the `message` to string and fetch the `value` using `regex` or the like..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called named tuple

```
for i in message.values():
...     for j in i:
...       print(j.value)
```

full code for some other user want to know

```
from collections import namedtuple

R = namedtuple('TopicPartition','topic partition')
index = R(topic='testing_topic', partition=1)

V = namedtuple('ConsumerRecord','topic partition offset timestamp timestamp_
type key value checksum serialized_key_size serialized_value_size')

content = V(topic='testing_topic', partition=1, offset=0, timestamp=14994113
65748, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value=b'{"url":"http://review.travel.rakuten.
co.jp/hotel/voice/158886/", "meta":{"url_cnt":"1185","hotelid":"158886","job_id"
:"0f3de6d4-34bf-4a1a-a803-5640e8d25932"}}', checksum=-309359221, serialized_key_
size=-1, serialized_value_size=158)

D = {index:[content]}

for i in D.values():
...     for j in i:
...       print(j.value)

b'{"url":"http://review.travel.rakuten.co.jp/hotel/voice/158886/", "meta":{"url_
cnt":"1185","hotelid":"158886","job_id":"0f3de6d4-34bf-4a1a-a803-5640e8d25932"}}
```